# Intersection of two string array list in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two strings in which both have set of numbers 
and I want the intersection to be the numbers that are common between them.
all of them are string

```
 ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

 list1.add(temp1.get(0));

 ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

list2.add(temp1.get(1));

 ArrayList<String> intersection = new ArrayList<String>(list1);

intersection.retainAll(list2);

 System.out.println  ( "Charstic sets Intersection  :::  "+intersection );
```

in which :

```
temp1 is : [[1, 2, 6], [1, 3, 5] ]

temp1.get(0) is :[1, 2, 6]

temp1.get(1) is :[1, 3, 5]
```

I am suppose to get the following :

```
[1]
```

but I am getting an empty set :

```
[]
```

Comment: If `temp1` is like you say, then `temp1.get(0)` is an array, not a `String` and your code would not compile. If, however, `temp1` is `["[1, 2, 6]", "[1, 3, 5] "]` (which would compile), then it's no surprise that the intersection is empty because `"[1, 2, 6]"` is not equal to `"[1, 3, 5]"`.

Comment: Better to consider about `HashSet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure the problem is the fact that temp1 is an **ArrayList of ArrayList of Integers** insted of an **ArrayList of strings**, that's why your intersection is empty. Hence it would probably be a good idea to convert your string into ArrayList of integers first.

I wrote a small example (called "test.java") of a function to do that: basically you split your string by the commas and convert your values into integers, then you can call ArrayList's intersection():

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class test {
    private static ArrayList<Integer> stringToArrayList(String s){ 
        ArrayList<Integer> ans = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (String t : s.split(",")) {
            ans.add(Integer.parseInt(t));
        }
        return ans;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> t1 = stringToArrayList("1,2,6");
        ArrayList<Integer> t2 = stringToArrayList("1,3,5");

        ArrayList<Integer> intersection = new ArrayList<Integer>(t1);
        intersection.retainAll(t2);
        System.out.println  ( "Charstic sets Intersection  :::  "+intersection );

    }
};
```

Output:

```
Charstic sets Intersection  :::  [1]
```

Let me know if the code isn't clear or whether or not this works for you :)

Comment: Your initial premise seems wrong. If `temp1` was an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList` of `Integer`, then the line `list1.add(temp1.get(0));` would generate a compiler error. Instead, OP is reporting that the code compiles and executes but computes an incorrect result.